LiveData is getting empty or null value in one case and correct value in other case. Can't get the reason of this behavior
I am trying to fetch "name" field from my firestore database, with two different processes. In both process, I am using a helper class to fetch data as Flow<List<String>> and then in ViewModel collecting it and coverting it as LiveData<List<String>>. But in one case I am getting the correct output but in other case I cannot. I don't know the reason of such behavior. Please help me to explain this.
I will provide you important part of my helper class, viewModel in both cases. And corresposding logcat message of both cases.
Case 1 (Getting empty or null value)->

ViewModel(important part)->
val firestoreHelperForToken = FirestoreHelperForToken()
private val _getAllNames = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
val getAllNames : LiveData<List<String>> get() = _getAllNames

init {

        //subscribe to a topic to broadcast the message
        viewModelScope.launch {

            firestoreHelperForToken.fetchAllNames.collect { namesList ->
                _getAllNames.postValue(namesList)
                // Log inside the collect block to ensure that the data is fetched
                Log.d("ChatViewModel", "List from Firestore: $namesList")

                // Small delay to ensure data sync if needed
                delay(100)

                // Check if list is not null or empty and log it
                if (!namesList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    Log.d("ChatViewModel", "Valid list received: $namesList")
                } else {
                    Log.d("ChatViewModel", "Empty list received.")
                }
            }

            // Log outside of the collect block after it finishes fetching
            Log.d("ChatViewModel", "List outside the collect block: ${getAllNames.value}")
}}


HelperClass(important part)->


class FirestoreHelperForToken {
private val TAG = "FirestoreHelperForToken"
private val _db = Firebase.firestore
val fetchAllNames: Flow<List<String>> = channelFlow {
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting up addSnapshotListener")

        _db.collection("tokens")
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed with error: $e")
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                if (snapshot == null || snapshot.isEmpty) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Snapshot is null or empty.")
                    trySend(emptyList()) // Emit empty list if no documents are found
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                val namesList = mutableListOf<String>()
                Log.d(TAG, "Snapshot size: ${snapshot.size()}")

                for (document in snapshot.documents) {
                    val name = document.getString("name")
                    name?.let {
                        namesList.add(it)
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Names list: $namesList")
                    trySend(namesList) // Emit the list of names
                } catch (sendError: Exception) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error while sending names list: ${sendError.message}")
                }
            }

    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)

}

3. Logs in this case ->
2024-10-06 10:57:26.586  1389-1422  FirestoreHelperForToken com.example.fcmpractice              D  Setting up addSnapshotListener
2024-10-06 10:57:27.296  1389-1389  ChatViewModel           com.example.fcmpractice              D  List outside the collect block: null
2024-10-06 10:57:27.299  1389-1389  FirestoreHelperForToken com.example.fcmpractice              D  Snapshot size: 17
2024-10-06 10:57:27.312  1389-1389  FirestoreHelperForToken com.example.fcmpractice              D  Names list: [mona, abhijit, mahesh, raka, ritu, ranna, jodha, biru, madhav, babu, rajat, sujal, mauni, meme, raghav, mamu, nammy]

Case 2 , gettting correct list(everything is same just a small functional change)->

HelperClass->
    fun getNamesFlow() : Flow<List<String>> = callbackFlow {
        val collectionRef = _db.collection("tokens")
        val listner = collectionRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error ->
            if (error != null) {
                close(error)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            if (snapshot != null && !snapshot.isEmpty){
                val nameList = snapshot.documents.map {
                    it.getString("name") ?: ""
                }
                trySend(nameList)
        }else{
                trySend(emptyList())
            }
        }
        awaitClose {
            listner.remove()
        }
    }


2. ViewModel ->
viewModelScope.launch {
Log.d("ChatViewModel", "List outside the collect block: ${getAllNames.value}")
     firestoreHelperForToken.getNamesFlow()
                .collect { namesList ->
                    _getAllNames.postValue(namesList)
                    // Log inside the collect block to ensure that the data is fetched
                    Log.d("ChatViewModel", "List from Firestore: $namesList")
                }



}
3. Logging->
2024-10-06 11:03:12.399  1851-1851  ChatViewModel           com.example.fcmpractice              D  List outside the collect block: null
2024-10-06 11:03:13.103  1851-1851  ChatViewModel           com.example.fcmpractice              D  List from Firestore: [mona, abhijit, mahesh, raka, ritu, ranna, jodha, biru, madhav, babu, rajat, sujal, mauni, meme, raghav, mamu, nammy]

I humbly request to please explain the reason of this different outputs in details.

Is the solution using a Flow working?

@AlexMamo Yes, case two in which I used the flow, it is working. I had tried using flow in viewmodel, but it is not working
